# Regular expression - such that a string does not contain specific characters

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I want a regular expression that would check if a string contains any character apart from "A" , "G", "C" , "U"
e 
the string would be like ggggugcccgcuagagagacagu

i want regex to check if it containns only these , it is not case sensitive.

what i tried

```
match= re.match(r'[^GaAgUuCc]',seq2)
```

It is to find non RNA characters in a RNA sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `re.search()` or `re.findall()` rather than `re.match()`:

```
In [9]: seq2 = 'ggggugcccQgcuagagaZgacagu'

In [10]: re.findall(r'[^GaAgUuCc]',seq2)
Out[10]: ['Q', 'Z']
```

Comment: I selected your solution as the answer because the search and findall functions did the trick .. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.search` instead:

```
>>> re.search(r'[^GAUC]', 'acg', re.I)
>>> re.search(r'[^GAUC]', 'acgf', re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f1b6a9e32a0>
```

`re.I` makes the regex case-insensitive.

A faster way to do it would be to use sets to check if the set of characters is a subset of your allowed characters:

```
>>> set('acg'.upper()) <= set('GAUC')
True
>>> set('acgs'.upper()) <= set('GAUC')
False
```

Comment: Could create the set once - `valid = set('gauc')` and do `valid.issuperset(the_string)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a quantifier with your regex to match more characters: -

```
>>> match = re.search("[^GAUC]+","ggggugcccgcuagrrragagacagu", re.I)
>>> match
9: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01BCA8A8>
>>> match.group()
10: 'rrr'
```

Comment: i dont wish to negate any case characters , it should not be case sensitive .

Comment: @njack.. Updated Regex.You can use `re.I` to do `case-insensitive` searching. Also, you should use `re.search` instead, if you want to search non-matching characters.